# Mac OS X Terminal Equivalent for Host Name Info

Tags: command-line, macos, hostname

In Linux, using a Bash Terminal, I can do:

- `hostname -d` to display the name of the DNS domain, and
- `hostname -i` to display the network address(es) of the hostname .

How can I retrieve the same information--preferably using a single command (with option, if needed), and without having to elevate privileges--from a Bash terminal in Mac OS X?

For reference, here's the Bash Version I'm using in Mac OS X:

- GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15) .

Answer (score 11):

For the `hostname -d`, use `hostname -f`:

```
hostname -f | sed -e 's/^[^.]*\.//'
```

For IP-addresses, use `ifconfig -a` (look for the `inet` data).  Your machine may have only one network device, `en0`, so you could do just

```
ifconfig en0 |awk '/inet / {print $2; }'
```

If you are interested in all of the network devices, keep in mind that `ifconfig -l` lists the devices.  This lists the devices and their correspond addresses:

```
#!/bin/sh
for name in $(ifconfig -l)
do
    ifconfig $name |awk -v name=$name '/inet / {printf "%s: %s\n", name, $2; }'
done
```

Further reading:

- [How do I find my IP Address from the command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20547/how-do-i-find-my-ip-address-from-the-command-line)
- [hostname -- set or print name of current host system](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/hostname.1.html)

Comment: `hostname -d` returns the name of the DNS domain, e.g. : department.business.com. Also, `hostname` and `hostname -f` are functionally the same in OS X.  `hostname -i` returns a network address (IP), e.g. 127.0.0.1. Your suggestion doesn't quite do what I'd like.

Comment: Using `hostname -f` with `sed` is an acceptable solution, as it parses out the DNS domain. Using `ifconfig`, though, returns the IP address, not the host IP.

Comment: I could, I suppose parse out the info by looking at `lo`.

Comment: It's not a complicated script.

Comment: Agreed. I was just looking for Mac OS X equivalents that didn't involve regular expression, if possible.

Comment: `scutil --dns` is relevant, but not that useful for scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I am using

`scutil --dns | grep 'search domain' | head -n 1 | grep -o '[a-zA-Z0-9.-]\+$'`

which seems to work under some circumstances better but YMMV. I make this an alias in my profile (for mac only) to `dnsdomainname` which works on Linux (in place of `hostname -d`).

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
ipconfig getifaddr $(route get 8.8.8.8 | awk '/interface: / {print $2; }')
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `hostname` command in macOS's Terminal, you may also be interested by the following command:
`/usr/sbin/networksetup -getcomputername`

(They don't return the same field, hence they sometimes don't return the same string, depending on how your mac is configured)

On the attached picture, `hostname` is returning "BCG-..." whereas `/usr/sbin/networksetup -getcomputername` is returning "BCF-...", and I found in most cases the latter one is more useful.

[image: Difference between hostname and computer name]

Answer (score -2):

Use 'dig'.  Search for commands similar to whois

dig hostname => both hostname + ipaddy

dig ip.address => not as complete

Comment: These commands seem to assume that you *already know* the hostname and/or IP address, while the question is asking for ways to ***get*** this information.  If I’m misunderstanding what you’re suggesting, please clarify.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.